# How to send mail notification after Azure Devops Load test is completed

Tags: c#, azure-devops, load-testing, status

I want to automate the workflow to send out mail notifications once Load test under Azure Devops project is completed. I get to see there is no direct option available for the same. Please suggest what could be the best suitable solution.

I have created a simple URL based Load test and ran it. One way I already tried is using Devops REST API and get the status in Azure function. But that is tedious process. Please help in this.

result expected is immediately once Load test is done, there should be email triggered to the group or individual members

Answer (score 0):

For now, the way you mentioned might be the way to go, as Azure DevOps does not provide notifications from this type of events OOB. Please submit your suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

References:

- [Default and supported notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops)
- [Supported event types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-supported-event-types?view=azure-devops)

Meanwhile, another idea I had was to have this test configured as a [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/cloud-based-load-test?view=azure-devops) in a Pipeline, so that you get an email notification sent upon build completion. However, do note that while the Cloud-based Load Test task can be added to a Job as of today, it has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops), with these options as [alternatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops#alternatives).